# Python: Find files in very large folder (over 100 TB)

Tags: python, bash, file, directory, bigdata

I am working on a program that compares entries in cataloguing software (Rucio) with the files in storage. From the cataloguing, I get a path to what it believes the storage location for the file is. I then search that location for the file to see if it exists there or not. I have successfully created a bash script that performs this, but it would be a lot better if it could be redone in python.

The problem I have encountered is that python will not find the files, even when I know they exist there. I have tried stuff like

```python
if path.exists(fulladdress):
    does stuff
```

And providing a file I know exists it still does not find it. I suspect it has to do with the fact that the folder is huge, over 100 TB and over 287000 files, so it does not search the whole folder and therefore does not find the file.

Does there exist a python solution that works for folders that big?

Best regards
Piotr

the bash script that works is:

```python
os.system("cd; cd directory_with_files; test -e file_in_directory _exist && echo filename >> found.txt || echo filename >> not_found "
```

tried running this:

```python
def findfile(name, path):
    for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(path):
        if name in filename:
            return os.path.join(dirpath, name)

def compere_checksum(not_missing_files):
    not_missing_files_file = open(not_missing_files, 'r')
    lines_not_missing_files_file = not_missing_files_file.readlines()

    #Extract a list of fiels i know exist
    for line in lines_not_missing_files_file:
        line.replace(' ','')
        line_list=line.split(",")
        address=line_list[0].replace("LUND: file://", "")
        #address= path to the folder 
        fille=address[address.rindex('/')+1:]
        #fille the mane of the file
        address=address.replace(fille,"")

        #search for the file using bash
        os.system("test -e {} && echo Found {}".format(line_list[0],fille))
        
        #search for the file using python function abovea
        filepath=findfile(address,fille)
        print(filepath)
```

address is something along the lines of "/projects/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/mc20/v12/4.0GeV/v2.2.1-3e/"

and fille is looks like this "mc_v12-4GeV-3e-inclusive_run1310195_t1601591250.root"

The script returns:

```
Found mc_v12-4GeV-3e-inclusive_run1310220_t1601591602.root
None
Found mc_v12-4GeV-3e-inclusive_run1310246_t1601592829.root
None
Found mc_v12-4GeV-3e-inclusive_run1310247_t1601591229.root
None
Found mc_v12-4GeV-3e-inclusive_run1310248_t1601591216.root
None
Found mc_v12-4GeV-3e-inclusive_run1310249_t1601591416.root
None
Found mc_v12-4GeV-3e-inclusive_run1310250_t1601591472.root
None
```

so the bash script finds it but the python does not

Comment: check if it is related with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609635/python-path-exists-returning-false

Comment: The total size of the files should not affect directory operations (like finding a file by name). Please [edit] your question to include more details, and preferably a [mre]. Examples of details that might be needed is the number of *files* in the directory (not their sizes), and the permissions on the files (together with owner information, and what user you're running your program as).

Comment: adding to my previous comment: exists() Return True if path refers to an existing path or an open file descriptor. Returns False for broken symbolic links. On some platforms, this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "the folder is huge"?  Do you mean that the sum of the sizes of all the files linked from a given directory is very large?  The size of the files should be completely irrelevant.  The only thing that will matter is the number of entries in the directory.  Remember that directories do *not* contain files.  Directories contain names.  And "folders" only exist as a gui abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I added the bash script that does work. In the files and the folder, I have only read permissions. For the minimal reproducible example, I don't know what to add, as the code rally just checks if a file exists at location or not.

Comment: by large folder I mean the sum of all files. the files themself are about 10-100 MB

Comment: It seems to me that `os.system("test -e {} && echo Found {}".format(line_list[0],fille))` checks for something different than `findfile(address,fille)`. What is the value of `line_list[0]`? What is the value of `address`?

Comment: Find all the unique directories and use multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

```python
import os

def findfile(name, path):
    for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(path):
        if name in filename:
            return os.path.join(dirpath, name)
filepath = findfile("file2.txt", "/")
print(filepath)
```

Comment: tried did not work (see edit in main post). bash finds it, python does not

Answer (score 0):

I can use:

```python
while open(file) as f:
     do stuff
```

Dont know why this works and not

```python
path.exists
```

or

```python
def findfile(name, path):
    for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(path):
        if name in filename:
            return os.path.join(dirpath, name)
```

but whatever, as long as it works it is fine.